# Delegates - Why were they created

Tags: .net, delegates

I think I've got my head round delegates; Now I know typically most 'things' exist to solve a specific problem, but what problem does a delegate solve.

IMO it solves the issue when we want to call a method which exists project we can't reference from another project (otherwise we may be in a situation where both projects are referencing each other which is not allowed). This makes sense to me and I can see the use.

Are there any other times / reasons / benefits?

Comment: Generalize "a method in a project we can't reference" to "a method that is chosen only at runtime".

Comment: Delegates came with linq and anonymous methods.

Comment: @Tomtom maybe they came into widespread use but they existed since .NET 1.0.

Comment: @usr: Not even that; delegates were widely used right from the start for anything event-based (e.g. WinForms GUIs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They exist so that you can put functions into variables and do operations on them. For example `Enumerable.Select` takes a delegate that tells it what to do with each element. How would you implement `Select` without delegates? You'd have to implement an interface for example but that is clumsy. (Java does it that way and it is not as nice).

Actually, delegates are very much like one-method interfaces.

They also exist for native-code interop so that you can provide a native function pointer to a native method.

Comment: I didn't think of it with Enumberable.Select - yes, I can really understand that!

Answer (score 1):

I use them in winform for example to close the form through a button.

```
button.Click += delegate{this.Close();};
```